# Conditionally populate list boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two list boxes, available and selected. I want to make sure that I remove any available options for the available if exists in the selected.

With my code below all items are put in the available and none in the selected. What am I doing wrong?

```
var availableTags = [];
var selectedTags = [];

var jsonAvailble = '[{"id":"1","name":"One"},{"id":"2","name":"Two"},{"id":"3","name":"Three"},{"id":"4","name":"Four"}]';
var jsonSelected = '[{"id":"4","name":"Four"}]';

availableTags = $.parseJSON(jsonAvailble);
selectedTags = $.parseJSON(jsonSelected);

for (var i = 0; i < availableTags.length; ++i) {

    //console.log($.inArray(availableTags[i].id, selectedTags));

    if ($.inArray(availableTags[i].id, selectedTags) >= 0) {

        $('#lstSelectedTags').append('<option value="' + availableTags[i].id + '">' + availableTags[i].name + '</option>');
    }
    else{
        $('#lstAvailableTags').append('<option value="' + availableTags[i].id + '">' + availableTags[i].name + '</option>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Well despite the `if` condition you do exactly the same thing on each iteration. Try doing nothing on the `else` (*or remove it*).

Comment: Make sure to remove any `selected` tag from the `available` list once it's selected. Otherwise, anything selected will *always* by available and will hence be added to the available list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var availableTags = [];
var selectedTags = [];

var jsonAvailble = '[{"id":"1","name":"One"},{"id":"2","name":"Two"},{"id":"3","name":"Three"},{"id":"4","name":"Four"}]';
var jsonSelected = '[{"id":"4","name":"Four"}]';

availableTags = $.parseJSON(jsonAvailble);
selectedTags = $.parseJSON(jsonSelected);
var selectedTags1=selectedTags.map(function(d) { return d['id']; });
for (var i = 0; i < availableTags.length; ++i) {

    if ($.inArray(availableTags[i].id, selectedTags1) != -1) {

        $('#lstSelectedTags').append('<option value="' + availableTags[i].id + '">' + availableTags[i].name + '</option>');
    }
    else{
        $('#lstAvailableTags').append('<option value="' + availableTags[i].id + '">' + availableTags[i].name + '</option>');
    }
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    Selected:<select id="lstSelectedTags"></select>

Available:<select id="lstAvailableTags"></select>
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you.  The .map() function is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter on the availableTags for the desired result

In the below working example, I am filtering all those elements in availableTags for which a value is present in the selectedTags.

```js
var availableTags = [];
var selectedTags = [];

var jsonAvailble = '[{"id":"1","name":"One"},{"id":"2","name":"Two"},{"id":"3","name":"Three"},{"id":"4","name":"Four"}]';
var jsonSelected = '[{"id":"4","name":"Four"}]';

availableTags = $.parseJSON(jsonAvailble);
selectedTags = $.parseJSON(jsonSelected);


availableTags = availableTags.filter(function(elem) {

  if ($.grep(selectedTags, function(e) {
    return e.id == elem.id
  }).length == 0) return elem;

});


console.log(availableTags);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, going old-school:

```js
var availableTags = [];
var selectedTags = [];

var jsonAvailble = '[{"id":"1","name":"One"},{"id":"2","name":"Two"},{"id":"3","name":"Three"},{"id":"4","name":"Four"}]';
var jsonSelected = '[{"id":"4","name":"Four"}]';

availableTags = $.parseJSON(jsonAvailble);
selectedTags = $.parseJSON(jsonSelected);

for (var i = 0; i < availableTags.length; ++i) {
  for (var j = 0; j < selectedTags.length; ++j) {
    console.log(availableTags[i].id + ", " + selectedTags[j].id)
    if (availableTags[i].id === selectedTags[j].id) {

      $('#lstSelectedTags').append('<option value="' + availableTags[i].id + '">' + availableTags[i].name + '</option>');
    } else {
      $('#lstAvailableTags').append('<option value="' + availableTags[i].id + '">' + availableTags[i].name + '</option>');
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="lstSelectedTags">

</select>
<select id="lstAvailableTags">

</select>
```